# PeopleSoft BI Publisher Parameters on second sheet of Excel output

Tags: peoplesoft, bi-publisher

I am creating BI Publisher reports from PeopleSoft 8.53.08 that output to Excel. We would like for all data rows to be on one page, but for all the parameters entered to run the report be output to the second sheet.tab.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the parameters as fields in the data source you are using to generate the report.  If you are using an XML source, it would be fairly easy to add a new element with the parameters elements underneath.  If you are using a PSQuery data source it is uglier as you would need to add each parameter as a column.  This looks funny in the query to see your parameters on each row of the query but it makes the data accessible in the report.

Once you have the data in your data source, work on your template and add a page break.  After the page break put the parameter fields you added.